# according to category ID get data

Tags: asp.net, categories, categorical-data

I'm trying to tell your friends. Services Service category and I got 2 tables. First Service Category I add. Then I added services connected to the Services category. So far, all right. Then I bring the categories of services under the Services menu on the front. Later on when I press service pages in this category comes from services related to this category. Etc. But there are writings in each service. Let me give examples; For example, I chose Soil Service Category = Sales are accordingly multiple services. These services are coming to the top of the page. Only this comes the contents of all the service. I want to bring only 1 of them. How do I make it according to the ID. I'm using the Entity Framework. And there is javascript plugin working.

```
 <div id="filter">
        <span>Kategori:</span>
        <ul>
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' Visible="false" />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkId" Text='<%#Eval("HizmetAd") %>' class='<%#Eval("ID") %>'
                            runat="server" OnClick="GetGallery"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- begin gallery -->
    <span>Gallery:</span>
    <ul id="gallery" class="portfolio-grid clearfix">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li data-id="#" data-type="<%#Eval("ID") %>" class="entry one-fourth">
                    <div class="two-thirds">
                        <p>
                            <%#Eval("Yazi") %>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>


    <span>Hizmet Resim:</span>
     <ul class="iconbox-carousel">
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <%--<li data-id="#" data-type="<%#Eval("ID") %>" class="entry one-fourth">--%>
                    <li>
                        <div class="iconbox computer">
                            <h4><a href="services.html#responsive-layouts">
                                <img src="/resimler/<%#Eval("ResimYol") %>" style="width: 220px; height: 150px;"></a> </h4>

                           <%-- <h4 class="entry-title"><%#Eval("KategoriAd") %></h4>--%>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GetKategori();
        GetGalleryByKategori(3)// Here is automatic id have to come.;
        GethizmetResim(3)//Here is automatic id have to come.;

    }

    private void GetKategori()
    {

        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("HizmetAd");
        dt.Columns.Add("Yazi");
        dt.Columns.Add("KatID");
        using (BesKardeslerPeyzajEntities krm = new BesKardeslerPeyzajEntities())
        {
            var krmekle = from v in krm.Hizmetler where v.HizmetKategori.ID == ID select v;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var k in krmekle)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                dt.Rows[i]["ID"] = k.ID;
                dt.Rows[i]["HizmetAd"] = k.HizmetAd;
                dt.Rows[i]["Yazi"] = k.Yazi;
                dt.Rows[i]["KatID"] = k.KatID;
                i++;
            }
            Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void GetGalleryByKategori(int id)
    {           

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("HizmetAd");
        dt.Columns.Add("Yazi");
        dt.Columns.Add("KatID");
        using (BesKardeslerPeyzajEntities krm = new BesKardeslerPeyzajEntities())
        {

            var krmekle = krm.Hizmetler.Where(h => h.ID == id).ToList();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var k in krmekle)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                dt.Rows[i]["ID"] = k.ID;
                dt.Rows[i]["HizmetAd"] = k.HizmetAd;
                dt.Rows[i]["Yazi"] = k.Yazi;
                dt.Rows[i]["KatID"] = k.KatID;
                i++;
            }
            Repeater2.DataSource = dt;
            Repeater2.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private void GethizmetResim(int id)
    {

        //int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Resimyol");       
        dt.Columns.Add("KatID");
        using (BesKardeslerPeyzajEntities krm = new BesKardeslerPeyzajEntities())
        {
            var krmekle = from v in krm.HizmetResim where v.Hizmetler.ID==id select v;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var k in krmekle)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                dt.Rows[i]["ID"] = k.ID;
                dt.Rows[i]["Resimyol"] = k.ResimYol;             
                dt.Rows[i]["KatID"] = k.KatID;
                i++;
            }
            Repeater3.DataSource = dt;
            Repeater3.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GetGallery(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
        string id = ((Label)lnk.FindControl("lblId")).Text;
        GetGalleryByKategori(Convert.ToInt32(id));

        GethizmetResim(Convert.ToInt32(id));



    }
```

Comment: Hello can anyone help me? Do anyone have idea? Help me ?

Comment: Dont have idea anybody ? İs this very hard?